# Cassandra Update - Some clustering keys are missing (timestamp)

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a Cassandra table that looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
    user_id INT, 
    message_id INT,
    received_timestamp TIMESTAMP, 
    status TEXT,
    message TEXT, 
    PRIMARY KEY ((user_id, message_id),received_timestamp)) 
    WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (received_timestamp DESC);
```

If I try to update a row such as:

```
UPDATE messages SET status = 'success' WHERE user_id = 1 AND message_id = 1;
```

I get an error:

```
Some clustering keys are missing: received_timestamp
```

I understand that I need to include the received_timestamp because it's part of the primary key, however I'm only including it in the primary key for ordering purposes.  Is there no way to perform an update here if I don't know the received_timestamp value?  If not, is there a better way to create this table that might work for this use case?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is user_id and message_id is unique for every message ?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam message_id is unique, but there could be multiple messages for one user_id

Comment: If message id is unique then how `received_timestamp` will sort you message according to timestamp ? There will be only one `received_timestamp` for an user_id and message_id

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra does not support ordering data across partition keys, because it will require a lot of network communications in distributed environment. But you can use ordering inside a partition key. If you want to get all messages (or slice of messages between some dates) for specified user ordered by message timestamp, you can use timeuuid type for message_id instead of int:

```
  CREATE TABLE messages ( 
    user_id int,
    message_id timeuuid,
    status text,
    message text,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, message_id))
    WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (message_id DESC);
```

`timeuuid` type allows you to have unique message id and sort messages by timestamp.

CQL has some [useful functions](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html) to work with timeuuid

But you should care about number of messages per user because of [CQL limits](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/refLimits.html):

> Cells in a partition: ~2 billion (2^31); single column value size: 2 GB ( 1 MB is recommended)